# align the textviews of my listview

Tags: android, listview

So I have one listview with some textviews and I want to align some of them like this:

```
Name      XXXXX

desc 

idade       18
```

And what I have is like this:

```
name

xxxxx

desc

idade

18
```

Layout of list items:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="vertical" >

      <TextView
    android:id="@+id/id"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone" />


   <TextView
    android:id="@+id/descricao"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="6dip"
    android:paddingLeft="6dip"
    android:textSize="17dip"
    android:textStyle="bold" 
   android:text="xxxxx"

   />
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/descricao2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="6dip"
    android:paddingLeft="6dip"
    android:textSize="17dip"
    android:textStyle="bold" 
    android:text="nome:"
    />

   <TextView
    android:id="@+id/data"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="6dip"
    android:paddingLeft="6dip"
    android:textSize="17dip"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

   <TextView
    android:id="@+id/data2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="6dip"
    android:paddingLeft="6dip"
    android:textSize="17dip"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/qtd"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="6dip"
    android:paddingLeft="6dip"
    android:textSize="17dip"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
  </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a TableLayout for aligning.

```
 <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/id"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/descricao"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="6dip"
            android:paddingLeft="6dip"
            android:textSize="17dip"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="xxxxx"

            />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/descricao2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="6dip"
            android:paddingLeft="6dip"
            android:textSize="17dip"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="nome:" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/data"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="6dip"
            android:paddingLeft="6dip"
            android:textSize="17dip"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/data2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="6dip"
            android:paddingLeft="6dip"
            android:textSize="17dip"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/qtd"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="6dip"
            android:paddingLeft="6dip"
            android:textSize="17dip"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Also, use "sp" for the textSizes instead of "dip" and "match_parent" instead of "fill_parent".

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is what you are looking for. But it seems like you want to keep descricao and descricao2 horizontally. For that purpose, you can keep this two view in another linear layout horizontally, like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  .......... >

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/id"
         ...... />         


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

           <TextView
               android:id="@+id/descricao"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:paddingTop="6dip"
               android:paddingLeft="6dip"
               android:textSize="17dip"
               android:textStyle="bold" 
               android:text="xxxxx"
               />

          <TextView
             android:id="@+id/descricao2"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:paddingTop="6dip"
             android:paddingLeft="6dip"
             android:textSize="17dip"
             android:textStyle="bold" 
             android:text="name:"
             />

       </LinearLayout>


    <!--your other views go here , ie in parent layout -->

  </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Linear layout inside Linear layout. OR you can try Relative layout, Table layout. ..

EXample:

```
     <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/id"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/descricao"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="6dip"
                android:paddingTop="6dip"
                android:text="xxxxx"
                android:textSize="17dip"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>
<-repeat other views ...->
    </LinearLayout>
```